# iPhone SDK - Can't upload Update to the iTunes Store

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios

I want to upload my Update to the iTunes Store (Universal App) but it doesn't work. Everytime I try it I get this answer: "An error occurred uploading to the iTunes Store".

I don't use the application loader (won't work) - I'm using the organizer in Xcode to upload it.

Yes, I have experience with uploading new Applications and Updates on this way, but I have no idea what happend now.

I hope there is anyone who could help me.

Thanks a lot, mavrick3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There just may have been a network error, or there may be alot of uploads going on right now, try back in a few, or restart your Mac. You can also try a Clean Build, that never hurts.